# Do transition metals only carry d-electrons as valence electrons until group 11?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

as I was revisiting my lecture notes in inorganic chemistry, I noticed that we treated the transition metals as elements where the energetic order of 4s ad 3d orbitals is reversed.

For example starting with scandium, it's valence electron configuration would be **3d3**, manganese's would be **3d7** , with the 4s orbitals only starting to fill with copper, **3d10 4s1**. Basically, the d-orbitals would be filled completely before an s-electron would be filled.

It wouldn't make a difference which orbitals (4s or 3d) start to fill first, if we're only looking at transition metals with oxidation states of +II and higher, but I revisited a problem in an old inorganic chemistry II exam. The d-electron configuration of iridium(I) was to be determined (in Vaska's complex).

The correct answer given by the university was 5d8. However, iridium (0) is 5d7 6s2, so iridium(I) should be 5d7 6s1, or is this incorrect?

Comment: The spectrum of singly-ionized iridium shows a mixture of electron configurations, see this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0378-4363(78)90101-8) (or just the abstract if you don't have access).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is most probably in the view that when there are 8 electrons in $5d$ the exchange energy increases and hence the stability increases as compared to the $5d^7 6s^1$ configuration. The extra electron from the $6s$ moves to $5d$ to achieve more stability by increasing the exchange energy.